# Buttons instead of select

Tags: javascript, google-maps, select, button, input

I'm working on a site and i want to use icons to select travel modes,
i have a working function but it only works with a selection input.
Is there a way to modify it to be used with buttons?

Thanks in advance!

Function:

```
function calcRoute() {
  var selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;
  var request = {
      origin: thuis,
      destination: kabk,
      // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
      // using square brackets and a string value as its
      // "property."
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
```

HTML - Select input

```
<select id="mode" onchange="calcRoute();">
    <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
    <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
</select>
```

HTML - Button input (?)

```
<form id="mode">
    <input type="button" onchange="calcRoute();" value="DRIVING">
    <input type="button" onchange="calcRoute();" value="WALKING">
</form>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `onchange` event for buttons. Use the `onclick` event instead

```
<form id="mode">
    <input type="button" onclick="calcRoute(this);" value="DRIVING" />
    <input type="button" onclick="calcRoute(this);" value="WALKING" />
</form>
```

**Edit**
And you have to adjust your `calcRoute` function

From

```
function calcRoute() {
   var selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;
   //...
```

To

```
function calcRoute(btn) {
    var selectedMode = btn.value;
    // ...
```

Comment: Note: The 1st line is `var selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;`. And there is no `value` in a form.

Comment: @Derek missed that. Thanks :)

Comment: @Andreas, too verbose ;) - `onclick="calcRoute(this);"` is way less painful.

Comment: @Alexander i didn't thought of this. Argh^^ Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! pretty stupid to mix up the onChange and onClick events ;-). I had someone looking into it and he got it working by changing the `function calcRoute()` to `function calcRoute(selectedMode)` and then stating the travelmode in the event: `onclick="calcRoute('DRIVING');"`

Answer (score 0):

```
function calcRoute(ev) {
    var ev = ev || window.event,
        btn = (ev.target || ev.srcElement);
    var selectedMode = btn.value;  //"this" will return the element in the demo
    var request = {
        origin: thuis,


<form id="mode">
            <!--Use onClick-->
    <input type="button" onclick="calcRoute(ev);" value="DRIVING" />
    <input type="button" onclick="calcRoute(ev);" value="WALKING" />
</form>
```

[image: This should work for you.] `:)` **WORKING DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/T7NrF/